# Add Widget after <header/> tag from plugin (Wordpress hook, filter, etc)

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title said, is there any hook to add a block of html code after  tag in wordpress?
Thanks in advance

Comment: __after_header @MadCoder

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by this way.

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'header_widgets' );
function header_widgets() {
if( is_front_page() ) {
    get_sidebar( 'homePage' );
}
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'footer_widgets' );
 function footer_widgets() {
get_sidebar( 'Footer' );
}
```

Comment: This is what I want :
<head/>
<body>
<header>
</header>
{{I WANT THE CODE HERE}}
</body>

Comment: @DhivaBanyuWigara Open header.php in the theme and place do_action hook there.